# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 .... on line 14

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I've got error from topic in the script below:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['password']);
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $password = md5($password); 
    if ($gender == female) {
        $sql="SELECT id FROM female_users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    } else {
        $sql="SELECT id FROM male_users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    }
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($link,$result);

    if($count==1) {
        echo('Hello');
    } else  {
        $error="Your Email or Password is invalid";
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I'm not sure what it is about..  i've tried to eliminate if statement, but it gave me no results.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` does NOT have db connection as a parameter. RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: what about $link ?

Comment: what about it? that's only for db connection and query. Oh, btw... `if ($gender == female)` that `female`, is treated as a constant here. and don't use MD5 if you're live or intending to go live.

Comment: `$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);` [Its all in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) **but thats a big secret, dont tell anybody**

Comment: Ok, i've got it (got double $link). Thnx

Comment: `$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
`

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: Is that really matters ? ;)

Comment: i've mean hashing ;p

Answer (score 1):

To go over the errors here:

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($link,$result);
```

The `mysqli_num_rows()` function does not take a database connection as an argument, so remove `$link,` from there.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Then your `female` in `if ($gender == female)` is treated as a constant http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php rather than a string http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php:

```
if ($gender == 'female')
```

and error reporting would have thrown you something about an undefined constant female notice.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Now MD5 is no longer considered safe to be used to store passwords with.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: try try try... that's all we see here. Not my downvote though. edit: now it disappeared *lol*

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: oh and you missed something. if you're going to make an answer, at least get all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

change count query to :

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```